# Convert Marathi script (non-arabic) numbers to arabic numbers

Tags: c++, number-systems

If we get value from edit box as Marathi '१.२' then I want this value as 1.2 in float format, I tried _wtof () but it failed it returned only 0. Its work same as _wtoi (). It's ok but -_wtof ()? Please suggest anything another function.

Comment: You could parse the string yourself, I guess. Or if there is a 1 to 1 correspondence of the symbols, just convert the string chars to digits into another string and then parse it with atof.

Comment: I assume '१.२' are numbers as written in the Marathi script?

Comment: Thanx Adrian Yes I was parse it but I think it's standard problem therefore asking a any api for conversion of unicode cstring to float value

Answer (score 1):

Actually `std::stof` and `std::stod` work just fine in Visual Studio 2015

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

double convert(const std::wstring src)
{
    double f = 0;
    try {
        f = std::stod(src);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //error, out of range or invalid string
    }

    return f;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);
    std::cout << convert(L"१२३४५६७८९.१२३४५६७८९") << "\n";
    std::cout << convert(L"१.२") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But `_wtof` doesn't work. You can use these methods if there is incompatibility in earlier version:

```
double convert(const std::wstring src)
{
    std::wstring map = L"०१२३४५६७८९";

    //convert src to Latin:
    std::wstring result;
    for (auto c : src)
    {
        int n = map.find(c);
        if (n >= 0)
            result += (wchar_t)(n+ (int)(L'0'));
        else
            result += c;
    }

    double n = 0;
    try { n = std::stof(result); }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::wcout << L"error" << result << "\n";
    }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << convert(L"१.१") << "\n";
    std::cout << convert(L"१.२") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

or using `CString`:

```
double convert(const CString src)
{
    CString map = L"०१२३४५६७८९";

    //convert src to Latin:
    CString result;
    for (int i = 0; i < src.GetLength(); i++)
    {
        int n = map.Find(src[i]);
        if (n >= 0)
            result += (wchar_t)(n + (int)(L'0'));
        else
            result += src[i];
    }

    return _wtof(result.GetString());
}
```